# I need to make a FMI-FMU Simulation in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, dll, simulation, modelica, fmi

I am a software engineer that recently tasked with an important mission at hand. My mission is to create a software that uses Unity Engine to convert and simulate FMU's. From what I researched so far I need to call functions in FMU's DLL's. Is there anyone who has this type of knowledge?

So far I read the documentation a little bit. Couldn't figure out how to do it or what should my roadmap be. I asked ChatBots to what to do and they said similar things like learn c# better, read modelica documentation etc.. Yesterday in order to understand more I asked Modelica Association and they gave me this reply.

"In any case, if you want to convert (whatever that means) and simulate FMUs, no knowledge of Modelica is required, nor you need to understand C to understand Modelica. FMUs compute the behaviour of hybrid dynamic systems, using either pre-compiled DLLs/shared libraries or source-code C, according to an API described in the standard. So, if Unity can call functions in a DLL, you are pretty much done, you only need to understand what they mean and when/how to call them, which is also explained in the standard."

So now, I never worked with pre-compiled dll libraries of another software. I don't know what to do. If anyone helps I would be really grateful.

---

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePlugins.html

Comment: I just saw that and immediately looked into it, thank you I didn't know this page on Unity. It will come in handy later on thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a soluation available to simulate FMUs in Unity: https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/Unity-FMI-Addon

For a general introduction to FMI I would like to refer you to the FMI beginners' tutorial from the Modelica Conference 2023 https://github.com/modelica/fmi-beginners-tutorial-2023 and the "Getting started" on https://fmi-standard.org/

Comment: Yeah I saw the unity one and already tried to turn fmi2 to fmi3 on its scripts but stumbled recently. I will start again from the beginners tutorial I forgot that thanks.

Comment: I realized I miss a simple part in Unity Addon although its not %100 converting .fmu file to a working 3D simulation it extract needed dll/c&h files the way I needed. Now I just need to make a simple Unity Project that does this steps automatically(Because since it will be an app it must not work from Unity Editor). Thanks for the help I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a popular package for simulation of FMU called PyFMI that you find here https://github.com/modelon-community/PyFMI and the report mentioned there by Andersson et al from 2016 give you some broader introduction that might be helpful for you. Another package is FMPy that you find here https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMPy, but here is no introductory report to my knowledge. The FMI-standard https://fmi-standard.org may also be useful. But I would start with the report by Andersson et al from 2016 that you can easily find on internet. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your immediate answer I will look into that and give a feedback.

Comment: Finally after carefully reading every document you've sent me I understood the assignment. I give my best regards to you sir you have my gratitude.

Comment: I already did for both but since I lack 15 reputation points It won't accept my upvote until I reach 15 rep. But it says it will auto give upvotes after I reach 15 so I will try to reach 15 as soon as possible by giving what I take from community :)

Comment: Good to hear! Custom is to praise answers by clicking on the upward triangle to the left of the answer. The reason someone degraded your question to -1, I think is due to the fact that the forum is focused on more detailed coding questions and not more general advice. But here is a grey zone and I do not mind your question.