How to create photorealistic 3D visualization of OpenModelica models in real-time using open-source tools?
While OpenModelica has basic functionality for 3D visualization of models by importing associated CAD data, the (photo-realistic) visualization is limited. Commercial products (Simcenter Amesim, Simulation X, ...) have this functionality.
The question therefore arises as to what the best solution is for displaying OpenModelica models in a photo-realistic and high-rendering environment using open-source tools.
My first thoughts were:

Add Real-time Library to OpenModelica
Export of the OpenModelica outputs using FMU or a communication protocol (e.g. OPC-UA)
Import of the OpenModelica parameters into open-source visualization (e.g. Blender, Isaac Sim, Open Dynamics Engine)
Return of relevant parameters to OpenModelica.

However, I have no experience with this workflow and would be interested in proven solutions!
Thanks!

See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77877959/i-need-to-make-a-fmi-fmu-simulation-in-unity/77878144#77878144

https://2017.international.conference.modelica.org/proceedings/html/submissions/ecp17132879_WaurichWeber.pdf mentions FMI-based and Modelica-based implementations in section 4.

Have you tried
https://www.sr-scil.de/simulationsbibliotheken/kommerziell-verfuegbar/visualization/ ?
However, although it is free and is a community edition, it seems that it is encrypted and you need to request for a binary version of openmodelica to use it. If you try it, I would be interested to know how it goes. Thanks.
